# Geyser timer malfunction

Tags: electrical, timer

Why would a geyser timer malfunction after only 14 months.? We had our entire DB board replaced and all new components fitted about  14 months ago. One evening about 5 days ago, I smelt burning wires and when I opened the DB Board, found that the geyser timer live wire on top was burnt and the timer did not switch off at the supposed time. The top of the timer was also melted. The entire DB Board was checked about one month ago for any loose wires and none were found. This %$#$# geyser timer could have been the cause of our house burning down. Emails to the supplier of the timer, Hellermann Tyton has not been replied to and I would sincerely like to find out what this happened.
THX   ***
JDN

Comment: Perhaps what it is connected to is faulty or a wire gets shorted by another fault...

Comment: Likely unrelated, but just to be sure **and to be safe**, is this circuit GFCI protected? Assuming "geyser" means "water spray", that is **critical for life safety**. It may also help, but not necessarily required, to be AFCI protected at the panel as that will catch certain types (but not all) of loose wiring type faults before they would result in a fire.

Comment: For Americans: the British definition of geyser, we call a hot water heater.